# Order items with single write

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-design, amazon-dynamodb

High level overview with simple integer `order` value to get my point across:

```
   id (primary)   |    order (sort)   |    attributes .. 
----------------------------------------------------------
    ft8df34gfx             1                   ...
    ft8df34gfx             2                   ...
    ft8df34gfx             3                   ...
    ft8df34gfx             4                   ...
    ft8df34gfx             5                   ...
```

---

Usually it would be easy to change the `order` (e.g if user drags and drops list items on front-end): shift item around, calculate new `order` values and update affected items in db with new `order`.

---

Constraints:

- Doesn't have all the items at once, only a subset of them (think pagination)
- Update only a single item in db if single item is moved (1 item per shift)

---

**My initial idea:**

Use epoch as `order` and append something unique to avoid duplicate epoch times, e.g `<epoch>#<something-unique-to-item>`. Initial value is insertion time (default order is therefore newest first).

Client/server (whoever calculates `order`) knows the epoch for each item in subset of items it has.

If item is shifted, look at the epoch of previous and next item (if has previous or next - could be moved to first or last), pick a value between and update. More than 1 shifts? Repeat the process.

**But..**

1. If items are shifted enough times, epoch values get closer and closer to each other until you can't find a middleground with whole integers.

   - Add lots of zeroes to epoch on insert? Still reach limit at some point..
2. If item is shifted to first or last and there are items in previous or next page (remember, pagination), we don't know these values and can't reliably find a "value between".

   - Fetch 1 extra hidden item from previous and next page? Querying gets complicated..

---

Is this even possible? What type/value should I use as `order`?

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB does not allow the *primary* partition and sort keys to be changed for a particular item (to change them, the item would need to be deleted and recreated with the new key values), so you'll probably want to use a local or global secondary index instead.

Assuming the partition/sort keys you're mentioning are for a secondary index, I recommend storing natural numbers for the order (1, 2, 3, etc.) and then updating them as needed.

Effectively, you would have three cases to consider:

- **Adding a new item** - You would perform a query on the secondary partition key with ScanIndexForward = false (to reverse the results order), with a projection on the "order" attribute, limited to 1 result. That will give you the maximum order value so far. The new item's order will just be this maximum value + 1.
- **Removing an item** - It may seem unsettling at first, but you can freely remove items without touching the orders of the other items. You may have some holes in your ordering sequence, but that's ok.
- **Changing the order** - There's not really a way around it; your application logic will need to take the list of affected items and write all of their new orders to the table. If the items used to be (A, 1), (B, 2), (C, 3) and they get changed to A, C, B, you'll need to write to both B and C to update their orders accordingly so they end up as (A, 1), (C, 2), (B, 3).

Comment: Yes, I was aware of that and planned to use GSI. I was considering this but there's one (big) problem - if you e.g shift item 25 between 2 and 3, you have to write/update over 20 items. This is a big no-no for my usecase.

Comment: In that case, you could go fractional - Start with the values fairly large numbers apart (1x10^100, 2x10^100, etc.), then when the 25th gets moved, set its order to the average of the two you want to insert it in between. DynamoDB offers [38 digits of precision](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html#limits-data-types-numbers), so it should keep you going for a while, though theoretically you'll still hit a limit if you never spread them back out again (but that limit is practically unreachable).